# How do I use and retrieve values from radio boxes?

Tags: sencha-touch, radio-button, extjs

Unfortunately, Im having to use radio buttons in a project. I cant get my radio buttons to display correctly. It only displays the last one. And it displays it as a text box.

How do I use and retrieve values from radio boxes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to  create an Ext.Panel

Then add a Ext.form.FormPanel

Then add the radio items to the FormPanel